# Can H2 database support queries that use structured parameters (sometimes called Table Value Parameters or User Defined Table Types )

Tags: h2

In MS SQL Server there is something called User Defined Table Types where you can basically create a parameter that is a table. This allows people in queries to pass a table as an input. This is commonly used to get around limitations with the maximum number of input parameters (such as in JDBC which limits the number of input parameters to something like 2000).

If I have queries that take in user defined data table types can H2 database support this?

Answer (score 0):

JDBC doesn't impose any limitations for numbers of JDBC parameters. JDBC drivers may have own limits and JDBC driver of H2 allows up to 100,000 parameters.

H2 supports standard [array](https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type) and [row value](https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#row_type) data types and you can pass these complex values as JDBC parameters too, but it isn't reasonable to use them to group unrelated parameters together to reduce their count.

H2 doesn't support any other complex data types and you cannot use MS SQL-style user-defined table types in H2.